# file_put_contents on OS X El Capitan

Tags: php, macos, file-put-contents

i am new to Mac OS X. Currently, i want to place a localhost on my brother OS X and host php files for him. I made a php that can take a picture and save it directly to the folder. The code is working on my windows 7 PC and i can use it normally. However, it is not working in the OS X as it always failed to store the photo in the folder locally.
My code to save the picture is:

```
<?php
require('includes/connect.php'); // Connect to database

$rmid = $_GET['id']; // Get product ID

// Fetch photo only if product id is not empty
if (!empty($rmid)) {
    $rawData = $_POST['imgBase64'];
    echo "<img src='".$rawData."' />"; // Show photo

    list($type, $rawData) = explode(';', $rawData);
    list(, $rawData)      = explode(',', $rawData);
    $unencoded = base64_decode($rawData);

    $filename = date('dmYHi').'_'.rand(1111,9999).'_'.$rmid.'.jpg'; // Set a filename
    file_put_contents("/foto/$filename", base64_decode($rawData)); // Save photo to folder

    // Update database with the new filename
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO foto(rmid,namafoto) VALUES ('$rmid','".$filename."')"); 
}  else {
    die('Rekam Medis ID is missing!');
}
```

I have already created the 'foto' folder inside the php folder. And i have given whole Read & Write permission to the folder. I am not sure why the photo is not stored inside the foto folder. But the query is working to store the filename to the database.

Added information: i am using XAMPP with PHP 7.0

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello efraim, do you have read and write permissions on the target folder?

Comment: @Rob Biermann yes i have already give read & write in the 'foto' folder as i wrote above, but still not working yet..

Comment: If you use terminal, and cd to the location where the folder is located, then perform `ls -l`, you should see the permissions, OS X is a linux, which means the rights work differently then a windows machine. Best practice for test environments would be to perform the command: `sudo chmod -R 777 foldername`. 777 will set all the permissions to read and write(fyi: right click->show info is usually nearly, but not totally the same) for more info about what i mean: https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: @Rob Biermann which folder should i change for the permission? the whole folder of XAMPP, the project folder, or only the 'foto' folder where the file stored?

Comment: Just the target folder for your pictures.

Comment: @RobBiermann Thanks! It's working now, thanks for the big help.

Comment: If you could upvote my answer, that would be nice! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to change the permissions of your target folder like this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *target_folder*
```

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Though 0777 permission shouldn't be a solution, get the user PHP/Apache runs on and check the permissions on the target folder, e.g 0755 should be sufficient for the folder if all is met.