# PHP failed to create file

Tags: php

I am learning PHP coding. I have a PHP code like this.

```
<?php // testfile.php
  $fh = fopen("testfile.txt", 'w') or die("Failed to create file");

  $text = <<<_END
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
_END;

  fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write to file");
  fclose($fh);
  echo "File 'testfile.txt' written successfully";
?>
```

Instead of creating my file I get the message "Failed to create file". According to learning book this is a permission issue. How can I fix this? I am using XAMPP on macOS Monterey.

I tried to alter the code by adding $functions but this didn't work.

Comment: The user as which the PHP server runs that code probably has no access to the work folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004623/file-put-contents-on-os-x-el-capitan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file\_put\_contents on OS X El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004623/file-put-contents-on-os-x-el-capitan)

Comment: No. This does not solve the problem.